# Windows cannot complete updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm trying to install update KB5029847 and update KB5029244 on Windows 10, but Windows gives me the "Could not complete updates. Undoing changes" message every time I try. Other threads about the issue seem to indicate that this is usually a problem with the version of Windows, but I am on version 22H2, which as far as I can tell is the most recent.

I've tried restarting the Windows Update and Application Readiness services, and using Startup Repair. Neither has worked.

The error code in the Update section of settings is 0x800f0922.

Comment: This sounds like a DISM restoration plus a sfc /scannow.  Hopefully someone more alert than me can give you the exact commands.

Comment: What you want is impossible KB5029331 superseded KB5029244. If you’re trying to install either of these updates your system is at least 4 weeks out of date (or as little as a week).  As for the .NET update do you have KB5029649 installed? What updates were last installed? Because as I pointed out you haven’t received an update since before August 8th which was nearly a month ago

Comment: As I noted a Repair Install normally corrects this (80%).

Comment: Does Windows Update say these need to install, or are you trying to install them manually?

Comment: In my experience a Repair Install will do all but some optional updates. That is how it has always worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Startup Repair will very typically not fix this issue. Since you ran the Update Readiness, DISM and SFC will not likely fix the issue. No harm to run them.

I suggest you run a Windows 10 Repair Install (repairs Windows). Use the option to Keep Everything. Nothing will be lost (but I always keep backups) and the Repair Install will bring updates to a current level and should fix the updates not working.

I have used Repair Install numerous times.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything